# Unable to create /root/.config/<app> programmatically

Tags: bash

I've built a script that places an icon in the launcher to open a program as the root user. This script also adds `NOPASSWD` to the user's configuration for this specific app in `/etc/sudoers`, however the one part of the script that refuses to work is the creation of the profile in `/root/.config/<app>`. I can create this manually, using the same `mkdir` command, but when I place the same command in the script it returns `no such file or directory`. I have replicated this behaviour a number of times, including on a clean install.

Is there some form of protection that disallows the ability to automate the creation of this directory? Or am I missing something about hidden folders in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are doing this when the `.config` dir does not exist yet.

```
mkdir /root/.config/<app>
```

Try this :

```
mkdir -p /root/.config/<app>
```

This will create any missing parent directory to the full path you provide.

Comment: Out of interest, when the command is first run (and neither child nor parent directory exists), does the command begin to create the directory path? If not, why did the command work when manually entered into a terminal prompt after the initial failure?

Comment: If you are referring to your initial tests, no, `mkdir` (without `-p`) should never create a parent directory.  I cannot explain your experience : I suspect something is not happening exactly the way you think it is, but I cannot be sure.